How to use provide in Vue's optional API to achieve bidirectional data transfer of basic data types?
There are two components. I want to implement two-way data transmission between parent and child by providing a responsive object. However, I found that the object type can correctly implement responsiveness, but the basic data type cannot. Why?
My personal guess is that the optional API will trigger automatic unpacking for basic data types, but it will not be triggered in the setup function, thus causing inconsistency.
//parent
<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  components: { Child },
  data() {
    return {
      message: {"name":"hello"},flag:false
    }
  },  methods:{
change()
{
  this.flag=!this.flag
}
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      message: this.message,flag:this.flag
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="message.name">
    <button @change="change">click</button>     
    {{ flag}}
  </div>
  <Child />
</template>

//child
<script>

export default {
  inject:["message","flag"],
  methods:{
change()
{
  this.flag=!this.flag
}
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <input v-model="message.name">
  <button @change="change">click</button>   
      {{ flag}} 
  </div>

</template>

Attempt: I consulted the official documentation and found that data() returns responsive objects, and basic data types can be passed correctly using the setup function.
Expected result: Bidirectional binding can be achieved when using optional provide to pass basic data types

This is fundamental to JavaScript. A value that isn't passed by reference cannot be updated this way:


let foo = 1;
function change(value) {
  value++;
}
change(foo);
console.log(foo === 1);



This requires to use a object that holds a reference to a value, this the purpose of the ref pattern:


let foo = { value: 1 };
function change(valueRef) {
  valueRef.value++;
}
change(foo);
console.log(foo.value === 2);



That a value is a property on this and not a variable doesn't make it different. flag: this.flag is the same as flag: false because provide is called once on component creation.
This requires to use reactive object that holds a reference to a value. ref won't work for this purpose in options API because it would be unwrapped when used in data, instead it should be an object:
  data() {
    return {
      flag: { value: false }
    }
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      flag: this.flag
    }
  }


Thanks for advice. The document mentions that the data returned by data is reactive. So it's because provide unpacks the basic data types, right?

Yes. This could affect something if provide() were running on reactivity updates like a watcher, but it runs only once, and writing flag: this.flag is the same as flag: false, as noted. There's no way how it could work differently in this situation in JS

It fits my guess. The provide function will not automatically unpack the object, the setup function  will not unpack the basic data type and the object. Thanks!

The provide and inject options are used for passing data from a parent component to its descendants without having to pass props down through every level of the component tree, and it should not be a solution for bi-directional data binding.
In your scenario, if you want the children update the object which will reflect in the parent. You might consider using a state management library like Vuex or Pinia.

This doesn't answer the question. provide/inject can be used for two-way binding. The docs cover this, https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity . There's no need to force the use of a third-party store, as they do exactly the same thing with provide/inject, at least Vuex

@EstusFlask Thank you for pointing out my issues. What I want to emphasize is that it's better to maintain the data flow from parent to child. Injecting an update function could also be a good option.

I agree, this is what the linked doc actually recommends
